# How to detect click in subview in hamburger menu

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, side-menu

So I have this hamburguer menu that pop ups via animation and I have a question. How can I detect if the user touched outside of the current view, in this case in the previous view that is just a little bit in the right so I can dismiss the current view. I'm having lots of problems with this because it seems like I can't detect anything on that right view.
Im using a table view controller and a transition to make the hamburger menu.
Im leaving 2 images bellow so you guys can take a peak and if u feel like it help me.

Thanks in advance guys!

[The side menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF8FU.jpg)

[The main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8L4c.png)